# Can't get $(window).bind('mousemove') to work in MSIE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In one of my web pages, I have the following JQuery:

```
$(window).bind('mousemove', function(){ ... });
```

I am finding a strange bug in MSIE 8 only; it seems to work as expected in all other browsers.

The listener simply doesn't apply, and no errors occur.

This seems to be a bug with `$(window).on('mousemove', function(){...})` too (note the function here is `on` and not `bind` as in the previous example.)

Comment: One thing that would help would be to explicitly state what problem you are experiencing.  You more or less just dropped code leaving it to readers to assume that it is not working as expected.

Comment: Yea it would be nice if you were clear on that before down voting me.  Practice what you preach.

Comment: Quite a few people downvoted you - I discovered your question only in the review queue tasked with deciding what to do with it.

Comment: I still don't see why people are downvoting.  If I had this issue and did a quick google search I'd want to find the simple answer that might not be obvious.

Comment: This may be a tech site, but presentation still counts.

Comment: There is hardly anything to present.  It doesn't error, it works fine in other browsers, and doesn't in IE.  Einstein said make everything as simple as possible but not simpler.  I did just that.  You might like to think there is more to this problem, but it is a simple stupid IE8 oddity that is simply just a matter of using document instead of window.  Good luck finding out why IE8 needs document instead of window.  It's a non issue.  It was presented here in case someone else had the issue.  There is no reason to know why, its nearly a dead browser anyway, so that would be a waste of time.

Comment: I'm afraid you **have just now** earned my downvote as well.

Comment: Keep them coming, I came here in case someone else had this problem.  If you're here not because you have this problem, then that's your own fault.

Comment: I find it funny that you are swayed by the comments and not the merits of the original question.  The original question is unchanged, yet you changed your mind based on comments.  Laughable.

Comment: Actually, the question is changed - I reverted my clarifying edit, because your poor attitude has lead me to give up on trying to get it reopened.

Comment: Fine, I editted it.  If you are unwilling to do the work on it, and actually DESTROY THE WORK you did on it, I will do it.  I asked this because I can see someone, it doesn't matter how seasoned or not, to slip up on this and be perplexed as to the cause.  It's even more laughable that you'd actually undo work you did.  Why?

Comment: I think we can all agree all this headache would be saved if IE8 was finally dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(document)` instead of `$(window)`

There is no great explanation, except IE8 is quirky.  ( there is no good reason for microsoft to have quirks, don't expect one )

Comment: a bit more extended explanation would be helpful

Comment: IE8 Doesn't seem to listen to `window`, but it does listen to `document`.  It's a simple small bug that doesn't error.  There isn't much to explain, I figure someone will search for this and find it if it happens to them, so no need to explain it a whole lot its an easy fix

Comment: A "why" implies a reason.  Do you really think there is a reason things don't work on IE8?  Why don't they have canvas on IE8?  What is the reason?  It just doesn't.  It's IE8, it hardly needs an explanation, merely a bugfix.